# PHP - SSL socket client certificate

Tags: php, sockets, ssl, certificate, client-side

I am currently using a tcp socket to exchange data between a server and a client using socket streams in PHP. I want each client to have a unique certificate (which I will generate for them) to access my server so that only people I know will be able to use it.
I have searched and found only how to use certificate on the server side, which will enable me to make a SSL socket connection, but what I actually need is to use a client server certificate to identify the client that is connecting to my server. Is this possible using PHP ?

I'd imagine the client to connect like this:

```
$clientCert = './clientCert.pem';
$streamContext = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $clientCert);
$server = stream_socket_client('ssl://IP', $error, $errorString, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);
```

But how does the server handle (identify, etc) this client side certificate ?

Hope I was clear with my question.

Thanks in advance,
Rafael

Answer (score 1):

You should use `stream_context_set_option` to set [`verify_peer`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php) to `true`; this will require the other side to verify that the client's certificate is trusted. The verification is done by checking that the certificate is signed by a trusted authority, so you need to specify where the authority's public key can be found through either the `cafile` or `capath` option.

Note that the above holds true both on the server side (to allow you to authenticate your clients) *and* on the client side -- the server is also not authenticated unless you explicitly make it so.

Comment: Okay, so on the client I need to set verify_peer to true and cafile to the path of the key the the _server_ ? Should I create a stream_context on the server as well ? If yes, what options should I set?  Btw, thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: @user2308602: You have to create a stream context on the server if you want to actually authenticate the client. Same options as on the client side, everything is symmetric.

Comment: There must be something missing on my server code. Currently anyone who initiates a socket to it can successfully connect, even without a certificate. 

On the server-side I create the context with the options:
local_cert = myCert.pem;
verify-peer = true;
allow_self_signed = false;
cafile = myKey.pem;

Then I create the socket:
`$server = stream_socket_server('ssl://0.0.0.0:500', $errno, $errstr, STREAM_SERVER_BIND|STREAM_SERVER_LISTEN, $streamContext);`
And listen to connections:
`while(true) {
$client = stream_socket_accept($server);
echo 'client connected';
}`

Any ideas ?